# How would I get all elements with a specific XPATH, get the lowest price among them, then get the title of it? [Using Selenium]

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working on something to scrape all element texts, somehow sort the number and get the title in it. I've gotten to the point where I can print all element texts but I can't seem to get the lowest number and title. I'm also only trying to get the elements that are "CARdano4SPEED__", and the number should only be 1-1000, if it isn't in that range, it shouldn't print. It should also only just get the lowest one of that. I'm not really sure how to go about that so any advice would be helpful, thanks!

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.jpg.store/collection/cardano4speed?filters=%257B%2522engine%2522%253A%255B%2522v8%2520special%2520edition%2522%255D%257D")

elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="asset-card"]')
for element in elements:
  print(element.text)
```

Which outputs:

```
CARdano4SPEED1120
1000
For Sale
CARdano4SPEED118
1111
For Sale
CARdano4SPEED117
5000
For Sale
```

Comment: you will have to get some data and process in Python. And you could use `relative xpath` (starting with dot `.`) to search inside every element separatelly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use dot `.` to create relative xpath and get title, price in every `element` separatelly.

Later you can get `title`, remove `"CARdano4SPEED"` and convert rest into `int()`. And now you can check if it in range `1-1000` and display or not.

And if you put it on list with `price` (converted to `int()`) as first then you can use `min()` to get element with lower price.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.jpg.store/collection/cardano4speed?filters=%257B%2522engine%2522%253A%255B%2522v8%2520special%2520edition%2522%255D%257D")

data = []

elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="asset-card"]')
for element in elements:
    title = element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/h4').text
    price = element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span[@id="asset-price"]').text
    prince = int(price)
    number = int(title.replace("CARdano4SPEED", ""))

    if number <= 1000:
        print('title:', title)
        print('price:', price)
        print('number:', number)
        print('---')

        data.append( [price, number, title] )
    
# ---

price, number, title = min(data)
print('min:', price, number, title)
```

Result:

```
title: CARdano4SPEED118
price: 1111
number: 118
---
title: CARdano4SPEED117
price: 5000
number: 117
---
min: 1111 118 CARdano4SPEED118
```

Comment: The thing is I wanna get the one with the lowest price and do something with that data instead of the minimum one.

Comment: then convert `price` to `int()` and put `price` as first element `[price, number, title]`

Comment: meanwhile I changed answer to get lower price.